# LOAD DATA INFILE id

Tags: mysql, import

I ran the following command:
    LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/Tyler/Desktop/players_20120318.txt' INTO TABLE players FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

On this data:

```
PlayerId,IsActive,IsVisible,FirstName,LastName,HeightFeet,HeightInches,Weight,Birthday,Gender,HometownCity,HometownState,HometownZip,HometownCountry,HighSchoolId,HighSchoolIdTemp,HighSchoolGradYear,CollegeYear,Redshirted,Transferred,CollegeId,CollegeIdTemp,CollegeGradYear,OtherAccountId,PreviousCollegeId,CurrentTeamId,LateralRecommendationReason,LateralRecommendationLink,CreationDate,CreatedBy,LastModifiedDate,LastModifiedBy,TwitterLink,FacebookLink,PersonalWebsite,PlayerImage,FirstNameNickName,NeulionID,OtherTeamID,OtherSportTypeID,SourceDataTypeID,PlayerTypeID,LoadID,SameNameTeammate,SameNameSchoolMate,SD_SportID,SD_PlayerID,ZeroNCAAStats,ModifiedByPythonGame,Missing2011,Transfer2011,RecruitingClass    
21,True,True,John,Frost,6,1,185,,M,Decatur,AL,35603,,{A0AD8B45-47E1-4039-85DF-756301035073},7453,2009,JR,False,False,{299F909C-88D9-4D26-8ADC-3EC1A66168BB},844,2013,{EBA5A9E6-E03E-4AE5-B9B8-264339EE9259},,0,,,2011-02-16 20:53:34.877000000,,2012-03-08 01:43:37.593000000,{5EBB0160-E69A-4EA2-89D5-932DD4D58632},,,,,,,45759,1,1,5,,,,,,,,,,
1344,True,True,Zach,Alvord,6,0,173,,M,Alpharetta,GA,30022,,{379BF463-67A9-480E-8FFB-9B50AD494953},11597,2010,SO,False,False,{7208C8FB-6780-4379-BC25-5DC5064C85FD},36,2014,{CDACD2C7-7667-406C-9662-02B378B00032},,0,,,2011-02-16 20:53:34.970000000,,2012-03-07 23:28:17.343000000,{5EBB0160-E69A-4EA2-89D5-932DD4D58632},,,,,,,45710,1,1,5,,,,,,,,,,
```

And mySQL was taking that first column (PlayerID) and assigning it to the id column.  It was also shifting everything over one column (first name was filled in with last name).

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Please take more than 8 seconds to format your question properly; it's a bit of a mess currently.

Comment: Sorry that when I pressed enter to submit my question I accidentally clicked in the text box

Comment: Do you have the `id` column set-up as auto_increment?

Comment: @MikePurcell good call, I forgot that the id column was automatically being created for me (I'm using Rails). If you want to type something to that effect, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Gotta love the ez fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that MySQL will properly insert the data by skipping the `id` column as long as it's set to `auto_increment`. Otherwise you can specify the columns individually as Bobby pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this problem, specify the columns you're loading data into and leave out the id field:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/Tyler/Desktop/players_20120318.txt' INTO TABLE players (col1,    col2, col3...) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Does `INFILE` automatically assume the first field is an id field if it is an integer?

Comment: `INFILE` will automatically try to load data for every non-auto-incrementing field in the table in order, regardless of type.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect, at least for mysql. the parens containing the field names needs to got at the very end. Otherwise, the answer is correct and behaved just as Bobby described.